# Loop through elements of list and include as value in the dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary output from aws service from which I need to extract the cluster name and it's corresponding ID. I am storing cluster name as key in a dictionary. I want to include ID as value to the key which is cluster_name in this case.

```
cluster_name = {}
for cluster in cluster['ClusterInfoList']:
        cluster_name[cluster['ClusterName']] =[] 
        break

kb = []
for broker in kfk_broker['NodeInfoList']:
    kb = broker['BrokerNodeInfo']['BrokerId']
```

Output of variables

```
cluster_name output
{'cluster1': [], 'cluster2':[]}

kb  output
1
2
3
```

I would like to assign the value of kb as value to the dictionary for cluster_name

```
Desired output
{'cluster1': [1,2,3], 'cluster2':[1,2,3]}
```

Any input on how this can be achieved?. Thanks

Comment: Could you please add sample input?

Comment: what is the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix your `kb` loop like this:

```
kb = []
for broker in kfk_broker['NodeInfoList']:
    kb.append(broker['BrokerNodeInfo']['BrokerId'])
```

Now, assign `kb` as value in dictionary:

```
for i in cluster_name:
    cluster_name[i] = kb
```